# How do I save and restore progress for N.O.V.A. on the iPad?

Tags: ios, nova

How do I save and restore progress for N.O.V.A. on the iPad?

I have tried everything I can figure out but there doesn't seem to be a way to save my progress. So I've only been able to make it through 2.5 levels before I run out of playing time and then next time I have to start over.

I'm sure it will be obvious once someone tells me, but currently it is very frustrating.

Comment: NOVA RULES! I'm "orokusaki", if you ever wonder who's been killing everyone so quickly. (ranked 724 in world, but moving up fast).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N.O.V.A. should be saving your progress automatically, and there should be a continue option at the top of your menu the next time your game starts.

If it doesn't, your best bet is to re-install the game, as this usually seems to work for others who had the same problem.

Comment: That's what I was going to say =)